# Create a measure which show your turnover per year

Tags: multidimensional-array, filter, ssas, mdx

I just begin the SSAS multidimension and i am lost.

I want to create a measure (in SSAS multidimensional) which return the turnover per each Year.

I have 2 tables in my cube : 
1 dim calendar which contains the attribute Year 
and 
1 fact table which contains the turnover

(So my measure "turnover per year" will be the same for 01 december 2010 and for 01 June 2010).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a Calendar hierarchy you can set to return the current year level value. For example:

```
(
Ancestor(
    [Date].[Calandar].CurrentMember,
    [Date].[Calandar].[Year]
), 
[Measures].[Turnover]
)
```

Comment: I add the function Aggregate and that's works thanks :).
AGGREGATE(
Ancestors(
    [Date].[Calandar].CurrentMember,
    [Date].[Calandar].[Year]
), 
[Measures].[Turnover]
)

Comment: I meant Ancestor(). It doesn't require the Aggregate() function since it returns a member instead of a set. One char fix. :)